# How to perform input redirection in python like the bash >?

Tags: io-redirection

I want to feed text files to a C program, with bash I can do `./prog <file`, how would you do the same in python ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you want to feed the input into an external program?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev yes I want to feed a text file to a C program `prog` so I can grab it with `getchar()`. In bash I just do `$  ./prog <file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that via [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["prog"], stdin=open("/path/to/file"))
```